# ZAP Passive scan rules are part of scan even after disabing them

Tags: owasp, zap

I am using ZAP docker image to perform API scans. I have disabled some passive scan rules in zap_started hook python script. Still, these are listed as part of the final report.

Script to disable passive scan rules:

```
pscan_id_list = [10003, 10015, 10017, 10020, 10021, 10028, 10029, 10031, 10032, 10039, 10040, 10041, 10041, 10043, 10052, 10050, 10056, 10061, 10108, 10109, 90001, 90026, 90029, 90030]
for pscan_id in pscan_id_list:
    zap.pscan.set_scanner_alert_threshold(id=pscan_id, alertthreshold='OFF')
```

Logs confirm rules are disabled:

```
2021-06-17 06:44:10,269 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:51008                                                                                     
2021-06-17 06:44:10,281 http://localhost:51008 "GET http://zap/JSON/pscan/action/setScannerAlertThreshold/?id=10003&alertThreshold=OFF&apikey= HTTP/1.1" 200 15                                                                                                                                                             
2021-06-17 06:44:10,288 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:51008                                                                                     
2021-06-17 06:44:10,298 http://localhost:51008 "GET http://zap/JSON/pscan/action/setScannerAlertThreshold/?id=10015&alertThreshold=OFF&apikey= HTTP/1.1" 200 15                                                                                                                                                             
2021-06-17 06:44:10,304 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:51008                                                                                     
2021-06-17 06:44:10,313 http://localhost:51008 "GET http://zap/JSON/pscan/action/setScannerAlertThreshold/?id=10017&alertThreshold=OFF&apikey= HTTP/1.1" 200 15                                                                                                                                                             
2021-06-17 06:44:10,320 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:51008                                                                                     
2021-06-17 06:44:10,327 http://localhost:51008 "GET http://zap/JSON/pscan/action/setScannerAlertThreshold/?id=10020&alertThreshold=OFF&apikey= HTTP/1.1" 200 15                                                                                                                                                             
2021-06-17 06:44:10,333 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:51008                                                                                     
2021-06-17 06:44:10,343 http://localhost:51008 "GET http://zap/JSON/pscan/action/setScannerAlertThreshold/?id=10021&alertThreshold=OFF&apikey= HTTP/1.1" 200 15                                                                                                                                                             
2021-06-17 06:44:10,350 Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:51008                                                                                     
2021-06-17 06:44:10,361 http://localhost:51008 "GET http://zap/JSON/pscan/action/setScannerAlertThreshold/?id=10028&alertThreshold=OFF&apikey= HTTP/1.1" 200 15
```

Passive scan rules are still listed in final report:

```
PASS: Vulnerable JS Library [10003]
PASS: Cookie No HttpOnly Flag [10010]
PASS: Cookie Without Secure Flag [10011]
PASS: Incomplete or No Cache-control and Pragma HTTP Header Set [10015]
PASS: Cross-Domain JavaScript Source File Inclusion [10017]
PASS: Content-Type Header Missing [10019]
PASS: X-Frame-Options Header [10020]
PASS: X-Content-Type-Options Header Missing [10021]
PASS: Information Disclosure - Sensitive Information in URL [10024]
PASS: Information Disclosure - Sensitive Information in HTTP Referrer Header [10025]
PASS: HTTP Parameter Override [10026]
PASS: Information Disclosure - Suspicious Comments [10027]
PASS: Open Redirect [10028]
PASS: Cookie Poisoning [10029]
PASS: User Controllable Charset [10030]
PASS: User Controllable HTML Element Attribute (Potential XSS) [10031]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `alertThreshold='OFF'` (capital T) as per https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/#pscanactionsetscanneralertthreshold

Comment: Thanks for reply. Script fails on using capital T:
zap.pscan.set_scanner_alert_threshold(id=pscan_id, alertThreshold='OFF')

TypeError: set_scanner_alert_threshold() got an unexpected keyword argument 'alertThreshold'

Comment: Ugh, so much for that idea :( I'll try and recreate this in a bit...